# what is the difference between lib-mingw and lib-vc2019

Tags: c++, windows

I'm new to Windows programming and found that lots of prebuilt libraries for Windows offer libraries like lib-mingw, lib-vc2019, lib-vc2017...

Could anyone help to point out

1. what is the difference? Which library should I use in what case?
2. If I want to use Clang on Windows, which one should I use?
3. Why these different libraries rarely seen on Linux (let's say
   Ubuntu), does package managers like apt hide this detail? In other word, why there's no such thing like lib-gcc.a, lib-clang.a on Linux platform?

Comment: 1. Mingw, VC2019 and VC2017 are different compilers. Use the library corresponding to your compiler. 2. I'm not sure but I think none of them will work with Clang. But it's possible that lib-mingw could work because its compiler is GCC and Clang and GCC are very similar. 3. These libraries are not seen on Linux because all these compilers are Windows compilers

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 through 2019 are compatible with each other and some versions of clang but not binary compatible to mingw or any other version of Visual Studio [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019) and [https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mingw (GCC), VC2019 and VC2017 are different compilers. Use the library corresponding to your compiler.
2. I'm not sure but I think none of them will work with Clang. At least on Linux GCC and Clang are very similar. I mean they are mostly binary compatible, many same compiler flags, many same compiler extensions. Clang tried to make it possible to easily replace GCC in your build pipeline. But all these information is for Linux.
3. These libraries are not seen on Linux because all these compilers are Windows compilers

You can always build a library with your compiler to use it in your project with your compiler (if you have the sources).

If it's a third party closed source library and you are a paying customer you can ask if they build it for you. It's usually better the add a new compiler to the build pipeline than to lose a customer.

Comment: I mean, why there's no such thing like lib-gcc.a, lib-clang.a on Linux platform?

Comment: @ravenisadesk Because clang and gcc are nearly binary compatible on Linux. By default Clang uses GCC's libstdc++ on Linux and you can use Clang's libc++ with GCC.

Comment: Any other way to fast port my Linux project on Windows? I use a lot of third party libraries, Integrate them all with source code are lots of work to do, what's more, by this I need to handle the dependencies of these libraries, which is nearly impossible.

Comment: @ravenisadesk That's a totally different question. Please ask a new question for this.

Comment: Regarding (2) - Clang on Windows requires either a GCC or MSVC installation (can either work with GCC's libstdc++ or MSVC's standard library), and has a separate executable that mimics MSVC. It's supposed to be compatible with the compiler you use it with. (I'm sucessfully using it with libraries compiled with GCC, didn't try it with MSVC.)

Comment: CMake and vcpkg can help with the porting. However those are not the only ways. And yes, I agree that you should ask a totally different question about that.